# Is there any way how to detect contact between SCNParticleSystem and SCNNode?

Tags: swift, xcode, scenekit, scene, scnnode

I have a problem with detecting contacts between [SCNNode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode) and [SCNParticleSystem](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnparticlesystem). I've already tried to set `physicsBody.categoryBitMask` and `contactBitMask` mask but it didn't worked. I've tried it on another node and it worked well. How can I do that on SCNParticleSystem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the [colliderNodes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnparticlesystem/1523516-collidernodes) API?